# oracle exact fetch returns more than requested

Tags: oracle, function, loops

I am having trouble creating a function that returns multiple rows. I am trying to use a loop but I still get the "oracle exact fetch returns more than requested" error. Any help pointing me in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sections2
(
id_param NUMBER
)
RETURN VARCHAR
AS
sections_param VARCHAR(40);
BEGIN
LOOP
SELECT sections
INTO sections_param
FROM table2
WHERE id = id_param;
RETURN sections_param;
end loop;
END;
/
```

Comment: A function cannot return multiple rows like this.  What do you intend to do with the data in the caller?  A function can return a `sys_refcursor`.  A function can return a collection of `varchar2` values.  A function can be declared as a pipelined table function.  We'd need to understand how this function fits in to your architecture to understand what the appropriate design might be.

Comment: I am trying to have it return multiple varchar variables. My goal is to create a function that returns all of the sections a particular ID is associated with.

Comment: Yes, but what is the caller going to do with those results?  As I said, your function can return a `sys_refcursor`.  It can return a collection of `varchar2` values.  It can be a pipelined table function.  Which you choose is driven by what the caller is going to be doing with the data.  Unless you know which of the three options you want...

Comment: The caller is just going to observe the data.

Comment: OK, let me ask a different way.  Are you returning results to a client application written in something other than PL/SQL that will just be iterating through the results and displaying them to a human?  If so, return a `sys_refcursor`.  Are you returning a relatively small number of results to a piece of PL/SQL code?  Then you probably want a collection.  Either an associative array or a nested table.  Do you want to be able to treat the result of your function like a virtual table so that you can do things like join to it and select from it?  If so, use a pipelined table function.

Comment: I am returning a relatively small number of results to a piece of PL/SQL code. I do not need to do anything with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a function that returns a collection.  I'll show an example of returning a nested table

```
-- Use whatever length is appropriate here.  
CREATE TYPE sections_tbl
    IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40); 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sections2 (
  id_param NUMBER
)
  RETURN sections_tbl
AS
  l_sections sections_tbl;
BEGIN
  SELECT sections
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_sections
    FROM table2
   WHERE id = id_param;
  RETURN l_sections;
END;
```

In the caller, you'd do something like

```
DECLARE
  l_sections sections_tbl := sections2( <<id>> );
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_sections.count
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( l_sections(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explaining what the process was to achieve my answer. I believe I am on the correct patch to solving my problem.